# How to retrieve 'custom user attribute' values using Microsoft Graph SDK?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, microsoft-graph-sdks

I'm retrieving the users from Azure AD with the following code. The user has a custom user property called `subscription`. I want to retrieve the value for `subscription` for every user. I can't find the custom properties under `additionalData`. What should I specify in the query to return the value for `subscription`?

```cs
var users = await graphServiceClient.Users.GetAsync((requestConfiguration) =>
{
    requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Select = new string[] 
    { 
        "displayName", 
        "id", 
        "givenName", 
        "surName", 
        "streetAddress", 
        "city", 
        "state", 
        "postalCode", 
        "country", 
        "userPrincipalName", 
        "additionalData"
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created one **custom** user attribute named **`subscription`** in my Azure AD B2C tenant:

[image]

I ran below **PATCH** request in [**Graph Explorer**](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) to assign **custom attribute** value to user:

```json
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<userID>
{
    "extension_<b2cExtensionsAppIDwithouthyphen>_subscription": "Sri Subscription"
}
```

**Response:**
[image]

To  **retrieve**  this value of all users from MS Graph API, you can run below query:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$select=id,displayName,extension_<b2cExtensionsAppIDwithouthyphen>_subscription
```

**Response:**

[image]

To get **same results** using Microsoft Graph SDK, I registered one application and added **`User.Read.All`** permission:

[image]

When I below code, I got **`subscription`** custom attribute **value** successfully in response like below:

```cs
using Azure.Identity;
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.Graph.Models;
using Microsoft.Kiota.Abstractions;
using Microsoft.Graph.Models.ODataErrors;
using System;

var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

var clientId = "appId";
var tenantId = "tenantId";
var clientSecret = "secret";

var options = new ClientSecretCredentialOptions
{
    AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud,
};

var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
    tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, options);

var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);

try
{
    var users = await graphClient.Users.GetAsync((requestConfiguration) =>
    {
        requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Select = new string[] { "id", "displayName", "extension_addbdbdda6df4198bxxxxxxx_subscription" };
    });

    foreach (var user in users.Value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(user.Id);
        Console.WriteLine(user.DisplayName);
        foreach (var subscription in user.AdditionalData)
            Console.WriteLine(subscription.Value);
        Console.WriteLine();

    }
}

catch (ODataError odataError)
{
    Console.WriteLine(odataError.Error.Code);
    Console.WriteLine(odataError.Error.Message);
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

Comment: Where can I get ```b2cExtensionsAppIDwithouthyphen``` in  ```extension_<b2cExtensionsAppIDwithouthyphen>_subscription``` on Azure portal? Is it the ```AppID/ClientID``` of the application registered under ```App Registrations``` which has permission ```User.Read.All``` to ```Graph API```?

Comment: In **App registrations** of your B2C tenant, there will be an application named `b2c-extensions-app. Do not modify. Used by AADB2C for storing user data.` like [this](https://i.imgur.com/lhnciWM.png). That application's `AppID/ClientID`

Comment: I can see the values of the custom properties after I put the correct ```b2c-extensions-app AppID```.